# Two fast queries, slow when combined

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this massive query that I am trying to add a left join to. **The addition is commented out.**

The main query runs < 4 sec, 32,000 rows.
The commented part runs < 1 sec, 51,000 rows.

But, when I combine them i.e join the second query, the whole thing runs in 15 sec.

There are already 2 massive joins in the original query (50,000 rows both), so I don't get why this join is special.

**PS: I might also be doing other suboptimal things, please criticize.**

```
select 
    *,
    case 
        when t2.status = 1 and t2.price > t2.buyprice then round((t2.price - t2.buyprice) * 0.04, 2)
        when t2.status = 2 and t2.price > t2.buyprice then round((t2.price - t2.buyprice) * 0.03, 2)
        when t2.status = 3 and t2.price > t2.buyprice then round((t2.price - t2.buyprice) * 0.02, 2)
        when t2.status = 4 and t2.price > t2.buyprice then round((t2.price - t2.buyprice) * 0.01, 2)
        else 0
    end as bonus
from (
    select *,
        case 
            when t1.gratis = 1 then 10
            when t1.price_vat = 0 or t1.price = 0 then
                case 
                    when t1.stock > 0 or soldLast180DaysQty > 0 then -1
                    when t1.stock = 0 then 12
                end
            when t1.buyprice = 0 then
                case
                    when t1.stock > 0 then -1
                    when t1.stock = 0 then 12
                end
            when soldLast180DaysQty < 0 then 1
            when t1.age_days < 60 then 9
            when t1.last_import <= 180 then
                case
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty <= t1.stock then 0
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty > t1.stock then 7
                    when t1.stock = 0 then 5
                end
            when t1.last_import >= 180 and t1.stock = 0 then
                case
                    when soldLast180DaysQty > 0 then 10
                    when soldLast180DaysQty = 0 then 11
                end
            when t1.last_import >= 180 then 
                case
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) < 0.3 and t1.stock_retail / t1.stock >= 0.9 then 5 
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0 and 0.1 then 1
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0.1 and 0.2 then 2
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0.2 and 0.3 then 3
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0.3 and 0.4 then 4
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0.4 and 0.7 then 0
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) >= 0.9 then 6
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0.8 and 0.9 then 7
                    when t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) between 0.7 and 0.8 then 8
                end
        end as status,
        round(t1.soldLast180DaysQty / nullif(t1.stock + t1.soldLast180DaysQty, 0) * 100, 0) as ratio
    from (
        select
            si.anqid id,
            CAST(rtrim(si.acident) as nvarchar(7)) as code,
            CAST(rtrim(si.acname) as nvarchar(100)) as name,
            si.anvat as vat,
            si.ansaleprice as price_vat,
            round(si.anrtprice, 2) as price,

            cenovnik.clientPrice,  -- <---------------------- This part

            round(si.anbuyprice, 2) as buyprice,
            concat(round(anpricesupp, 2), ' ', acpurchcurr) as fakturna,
            round(si.anrtprice - si.anbuyprice, 2) as profit,
            case
                when si.anrtprice is not null and si.anrtprice > 0 and si.anbuyprice is not null and si.anbuyprice > 0
                then round((si.anrtprice / si.anbuyprice - 1) * 100, 0)
            end as margin,
            cast(si.acfieldsa as nvarchar(12)) as [group],
            cast(rtrim(si.acClassif2) as nvarchar(16)) as category,
            cast(rtrim(ss.acsubject) as nvarchar(7)) as supplier_code,
            cast(left(ss.acname2, 30) as nvarchar(30)) as supplier_name,
            rtrim(si.acclassif) as rebate,
            si.anFieldNA as webActive,
            si.anfieldNF as gratis,
            case
                when si.acpicture is not null then 'true'
                else 'false'
            end as picture,
            isnull((select sum(anstock) from the_stock where acident = si.acident and acwarehouse = '00051'), 0) as stock_warehouse,
            isnull((select sum(anstock) from the_stock where acident = si.acident and acwarehouse <> '00051'), 0) as stock_retail,
            isnull((select sum(anstock) from the_stock where acident = si.acident), 0) as stock,
            isnull((select sum(anReserved) from the_stock where acident = si.acident), 0) as stock_reserved,
            isnull((select sum(anvalue) from the_stock where acident = si.acident), 0) as stock_value,
            (
                select isnull(datediff(day, max(m.addate), getdate()), 9999)
                    from the_moveitem mi
                        left join the_move m
                            on mi.ackey = m.ackey
                    where mi.acident = si.acident and m.acDocType in ('1900', '1000', '6800', '1A00')
            ) as last_import,
            isnull(round(soldLast180Days.soldLast180DaysQty, 0), 0) soldLast180DaysQty,
            isnull(round(soldLast180Days.soldLast180DaysCogs, 0), 0) soldLast180DaysCogs,
            isnull(round(soldLast180Days.soldLast180DaysRevenue, 0), 0) soldLast180DaysRevenue,
            isnull(round(soldLast180Days.soldLast180DaysProfit, 0), 0) soldLast180DaysProfit,
            datediff(day, si.adtimeins, getdate()) as age_days
        from the_setitem si


            /*
            left join (
                SELECT
                    si.acident sku,
                    case
                        when dogovoren.anPrice is null and matrica.anRebate is null then si.anRTPrice
                        when dogovoren.anPrice is not null then dogovoren.anPrice
                        when dogovoren.anPrice is null then si.anRTPrice * (1 - matrica.anRebate/100)
                    end as clientPrice
                FROM tHE_SetItem si
                    left join (
                        select acident, anPrice 
                        from vHE_SetSubjPriceItemExtToday 
                        where acsubject = '1111'
                    ) dogovoren
                        on dogovoren.acident = si.acident
                    left join (
                        select acClassif, anRebate 
                        from vHE_SetSubjTypePriceCateg 
                        where acSubjType = (select acsubjtypebuyer from tHE_SetSubj where acsubject = '1111')
                    ) matrica
                        on si.acClassif = matrica.acClassif
            ) cenovnik
                on cenovnik.sku = si.acident
            */


            left join tHE_SetSubj ss
                on ss.acsubject = si.acsupplier
            left join (
                select 
                    mi.acident, 
                    sum(mi.anQty) soldLast180DaysQty,
                    sum(mi.anQty * mi.anStockPrice) soldLast180DaysCogs,
                    sum(mi.anPVVATBase) soldLast180DaysRevenue,
                    sum(mi.anPVVATBase - mi.anQty * mi.anStockPrice) soldLast180DaysProfit
                from the_moveitem mi
                    left join the_move m
                        on m.ackey = mi.ackey
                where m.acDocType in ('3000', '3050', '3190', '3800', '3550', '3X10', '3950', '3500', '3510', '6700', '3A00', '3210', '3220', '3230', '3240', '3450', '3250', '3260', '3270', '3540', '3460', '3280', '3290', '3310', '3320', '3440', '3330', '3340', '3350', '3360', '3370', '3380', '3390', '3410', '3470', '3420', '3430', '3480', '3490', '3520', '3530', '3560', '3610', '2540', '2740', '2730'
                ) and m.addate >= getdate() - 180
                group by mi.acident
            ) soldLast180Days
                on soldLast180Days.acIdent = si.acident
        ) t1
) t2
where 
    t2.status < 11
order by 
    t2.status asc,
    t2.stock_value desc
```

I am using SQL Server if it's relevant.

Comment: As this is a performance question we need to have the explain and table structures of every table involved in the query..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Are you talking about every table, or just the ones from the join? The tables are massive, and I'm afraid they would clutter the question into oblivion. Maybe I can post specific columns from the table descriptions; which ones are important?

Comment: iám talking about a complete `CREATE TABLE ...` structures for every table as we need to know columns data types and indexes...

Comment: But first start with posting a EXPLAIN plan maybe that gives us enough hints

Comment: Yes there are a ton of columns. Just for one of the tables `the_setitem`, the `CREATE TABLE` query is 1,008 LOC.

Comment: Why `CAST(rtrim(si.acident) as nvarchar(7)) sku`? `RTRIM` is superfluous since SQL Server ignores trailing spaces when comparing strings. If you can change that to `si.acident AS sku`, it might allow indexes to be used more efficiently. Basically, applying functions to columns ultimately used in `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause predicates is bad as it affects cardinality estimates and may preclude use of indexes.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, cleaning that part up did nothing for the speed. It makes no sense to me why this join is a problem, and the others are not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer - but when I've had this problem I've just created temporary tables. In SQL Server you prefix the table name with # and they will get deleted when your session ends.

You might realise your nested table t1 as a temporary table #t1

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (id INT, code NVARCHAR(7), etc...)
INSERT INTO #t1
    select
        si.anqid id,
        CAST(rtrim(si.acident) as nvarchar(7)) as code,
        CAST(rtrim(si.acname) as nvarchar(100)) as name,
        etc..
SELECT * FROM ....  #t1 ...
```

Replace all references to t1 with #t1

Comment: Interesting! This brought down the 15 sec execution time down to 4 sec. Why does this work?

Comment: SQL Server has a terrific query optimiser that nearly always does better than you can "by hand". But it's not magic and it does get things wrong. Sometimes we need to accept that and give it a clue. And, to be fair to the optimiser - that is a monster query you've got there!